# Cannot get values of <apex:selectRadio> when inside <apex:repeat>

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

When I setup a visualforce page with a `<apex:selectRadio>` that is inside a repeat, I cant seem to get the selected value back into the controller.  If I move it out of the repeat, it works fine.  Any ideas?

Controller:

```
public with sharing class COPE_TestsExt {
public id tid {get;set;}
public boolean showTestSelect {get;set;}
public list<COPE_Tests__c> tests {get;set;}
public list<COPE_questions__c> questions {get;set;}
public list<List<SelectOption>> options {get;set;}
public COPE_results__c results {get;set;}
public list<string> rid {get;set;}   

public COPE_TestsExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {   

    results = new COPE_results__c();
    showTestSelect = true;
    tests = [select id, name from COPE_Tests__c];
    tid = null; 

}

public PageReference setTid(){

    integer ridCount = 0;       
    showTestSelect = false;
    tid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('tid');
    results.cope_test__c = tid;
    questions = [select id, name, question_body__c, (select id, name, option_body__c from COPE_options__r order by name ASC) from COPE_questions__c ];
    options = new List<List<SelectOption>>();
    for(COPE_Questions__C q : questions){
        ridCount++;
        List<SelectOption> l = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(COPE_options__c op : q.COPE_options__r){
            l.add(new SelectOption(string.valueof(op.id), op.option_body__c));
        }
        options.add(l);
    }
    rid = new string[ridCount];
    integer tempCount = 0;
    while(tempCount < ridCount){
    rid[tempCount] = '';
    tempCount++;
    }

    return null;
}      
public pagereference submit(){
  return null;
}       
}
```

Page:

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="COPE_Tests__c" extensions="COPE_TestsExt" >
<apex:form id="theForm" >
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:outputPanel id="testSelect">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tests}" var="t" rendered="{!showTestSelect}"  >
    <apex:column headerValue="Please select a test:" ><apex:commandLink reRender="testSelect,testPage" action="{!setTID}"  >{!t.name}<apex:param name="tid" value="{!t.id}"/></apex:commandLink></apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="testPage">
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!not(showTestSelect)}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="User Information" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField label="What is your full name?" value="{!results.name}" required="false"/>
        <apex:inputField label="What is your email address?" value="{!results.Email__c}" required="false"/>
        <apex:inputField label="What is your OE Tracker #?" value="{!results.OE_Tracker__c}" required="false"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Test Questions" columns="1">
    <apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="q">
    {!count+1}. {!q.Question_Body__c}
    <apex:repeat first="{!count}" rows="1" value="{!options}" var="op">
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!rid[count]}" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!op}" />
    </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:repeat>
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
<apex:commandButton reRender="check" action="{!submit}" value="Submit"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputtext>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel id="check">
{!rid[0]}
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I found this post but I dont understand: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Get-the-values-from-visualforce-to-apex/td-p/206304

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: relevant code added.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got it right you want to store in

```
public list<List<SelectOption>> options {get;set;}
```

possible answers. So a better approach might be to store it in a map from Question.Id to List like this

```
public Map<Id,List<SelectOption>> options {get;set;}
...    
for(COPE_Questions__C q : questions){
    ridCount++;
    List<SelectOption> l = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(COPE_options__c op : q.COPE_options__r){
        l.add(new SelectOption(string.valueof(op.id), op.option_body__c));
    }
    options.put(q.Id,l);
}
```

And then in VF Page you could do something like

```
<apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="q">
  {!count+1}. {!q.Question_Body__c}
<apex:selectRadio value="{!rid[count]}" >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!options[q.Id]}" />
</apex:selectRadio>
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. I might misunderstood your code (hes not very readable) if so don't get angry :)

Comment: I implemented your idea, and now returning some data, but is still not fully working.  Its only returning values for `rid[0]` and for that it returns the ids of the option chosen for the last question in the repeat.  Your answer did solve the problem I asked about though.  Any thoughts on the new problem?  My guess is that for some reason all the  `selectRadio`s are getting the value `{!rid[0]}1 instead of incrementing, but the question bodies are getting numbered correctly, so im not sure why that would be.

Comment: Does count really increments ? E.g. in {!count+1}. {!q.Question_Body__c} You see 1. "Question Body" on all the questions ?

Comment: Yes, it is incrementing there. It shows 1. for the first, 2. for the second and so on.  So it must be some other issue...

Comment: I inspected the elements, and it seems all the radio boxes have the same values for _name_, _id_, and _for_

Comment: I think I found it, I was running into an error "Subscript value X not valid. Must be between 0 and Y" when I would press submit so I added: `<apex:commandbutton immediate="yes" reRender="check" action="{!submit}" value="Submit">
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}"/>
</apex:commandbutton>`, but without that im not getting anything returned at all

Comment: OK, thanks Moti so much! with your help getting me to understand maps, I built a second map to store a integer associated with each question and used that instead of the `count` thing I had setup and it worked!  Whats the etiquette here? should I paste my working code somewhere?

Comment: Glad i could help. I think your description of solution is enough for someone who will come back (shortly - use maps :) so it's fine.